# Binary insertion sort

Tags: java

```
package BinarySearchSort;

public class Program
{
    public static class Student
    {
        public int ID;
        public String name;
        public int age;
        public double GPA;

        // constructor
        public Student(int ID, String name, int age, double GPA)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.GPA = GPA;
        }

    } // class Student

    public static int BinarySearch(int A[],
                                   int k, 
                                   int p, int q)

    {
        int m;  


        if (p>q) 
        {
          System.out.print("Error in BinarySearch: the routine was called with p > q");
          Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
          r.exit(0);    
        } 

        while (p != q) 
        {
            m = (p + q) / 2; 
            if (A[m] > A[k])
                q = m ;     
            else if (A[m] < A[k])
                p = m + 1;
            else
                return m;  
         } 

         return p;

    } 


    public static void InsertionSort(int A[])
    {
        int k,temp;
        int N = A.length;


            System.out.print("        ");
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) System.out.print("[" + j + "]");
            System.out.println();
            // values
            System.out.print("         ");
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) System.out.print(" " + A[j] + " ");
            System.out.println();

        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {

            k = BinarySearch(A, i, 0, i);


            System.out.print("Place "+ A[i]+ " on position " + k + ":");


            for (int j = i; j - 1 >= k; j--)
            {   
                temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j - 1];
                A[j - 1] = temp;
            } 


            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) System.out.print(" " + A[j] + " ");
            System.out.println();


            try 
            {
                System.in.read();
            }
            catch (java.io.IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } 
    } 


    public static int BinarySearchStructure(Student A[], 
                                   int k, 
                                   int p, int q)  
    {
        int m;  


        if (p > q)
        {
            System.out.print("Error in BinarySearch: the routine was called with p > q");
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            r.exit(0);  
        }

        while (p != q)
        {
            m = (p + q) / 2; 
            if (A[m].ID > A[k].ID)
                q = m;  
            else if (A[m].ID < A[k].ID)
                p = m + 1;
            else
                return m;  
        } 

        return p;

    } 


    public static void InsertionSortStructure(Student A[])
    {
        int k; 
        int N = A.length;
        Student temp = new Student(0,"",0,0.0);


        String spacesString = "           ";
        int distances[] = new int[N];

        System.out.print(spacesString);
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("[" + j + "]");
            distances[j] = A[j].name.length() - "[0]".length() + 1;
            for (int n = 0; n < distances[j]; n++) System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();


        System.out.print(spacesString+" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(A[j].ID+"  ");
            for (int n = 0; n < distances[j]; n++) System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();


        System.out.print(spacesString + " ");
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) System.out.print(A[j].name + " ");
        System.out.println();


        System.out.print(spacesString+" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(A[j].age + " ");
            for (int n = 0; n < distances[j]; n++) System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();


        System.out.print(spacesString+" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(A[j].GPA + " ");
            for (int n = 0; n < distances[j]-1; n++) System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(spacesString);
        System.out.println();


        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {

            k = BinarySearchStructure(A, i, 0, i);


            System.out.println("Place " + A[i].name + " on position " + k + ":");


            for (int j = i; j - 1 >= k; j--)
            {   
                temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j - 1];
                A[j - 1] = temp;
            } 


            System.out.print(spacesString + " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(A[j].ID + "  ");
                for (int n = 0; n < distances[j]; n++) System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();


            System.out.print(spacesString + " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) System.out.print(A[j].name + " ");
            System.out.println();


            System.out.print(spacesString + " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(A[j].age + " ");
                for (int n = 0; n < distances[j]; n++) System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();


            System.out.print(spacesString + " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(A[j].GPA + " ");
                for (int n = 0; n < distances[j]-1; n++) System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(spacesString);
            System.out.println();


            try
            {
                System.in.read();
            }
            catch (java.io.IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        int maxNumStudents = 10;
        Student[] A = new Student[maxNumStudents];  
        java.io.BufferedReader file;
        String line; 
        String[] studentTextData;
        java.util.StringTokenizer tokenizer;

        String fileName = "Students.txt";
        System.out.println("List(unsorted) of students from comma delimited file "+ fileName );
        System.out.println();

        int studentNum = -1;
        try {
            file = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(fileName));
            while (studentNum < maxNumStudents-1)
            {
                studentNum++;

                if ((line = file.readLine()) == null) {
                    System.out.println("The file has less than "+maxNumStudents+" records.");
                    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    r.exit(0);  
                }


                tokenizer = new java.util.StringTokenizer(line, ",");


                A[studentNum] = new Student(
                    Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken().trim()), // ID
                    tokenizer.nextToken().trim(), // name
                    Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken().trim()), // age
                    Double.parseDouble(tokenizer.nextToken().trim())); // GPA

                System.out.println(A[studentNum].ID + " "+ // ID
                                    A[studentNum].name + " "+ //name
                                    A[studentNum].age + " "+ //age
                                    A[studentNum].GPA); // GPA

            } 
            file.close();

        } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e)   {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Sort by Binary Insertion Algorithm :");
        System.out.println();

        InsertionSortStructure(A);

        String sortedFile = "Students_sorted.txt";
        java.io.BufferedWriter outFile;

        System.out.println("Sorted list of students from comma delimited file " + fileName);
        System.out.println("was output to file " +sortedFile);
        try {
            outFile = new java.io.BufferedWriter(new java.io.FileWriter(sortedFile));

            for (studentNum = 0; studentNum < maxNumStudents; studentNum++)
            {   
                System.out.println(A[studentNum].ID + " " + // ID
                            A[studentNum].name + " " + //name
                            A[studentNum].age + " " + //age
                            A[studentNum].GPA); // GPA


                outFile.write(A[studentNum].ID + " " + // ID
                            A[studentNum].name + " " + //name
                            A[studentNum].age + " " + //age
                            A[studentNum].GPA); // GPA
                outFile.newLine();
            }
            outFile.close();

        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 
}
```

I get the compiling error .....

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
No enclosing instance of type Program is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Program (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Program).
at BinarySearchSort.Program.main(Program.java:279)
```

Comment: Do you *need* to use those nested classes? Your code sample is badly formatted, probably unnecessarily long (we don't need the sort implementation or basically any line that doesn't have the compiler error here), and you didn't point out which line is `279`. Just break your code up into independent classes and you'll probably see where the problem is since it will change into a more obvious scoping issue.

Comment: That program compiles and runs correctly on my machine. Try refreshing your project.